# How Can I Make Profile Page Like This..?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

https://ibb.co/r6jbxV3
Hi Everyone I want screen like this, ı cant create dropdown button. How I can Create Like This Screen?
Please Help .

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ProfileupdateScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `Image`, `Text` and `TextFormField` in `Column`.

Comment: So what should be the main widget? And ı want to gradient color background. Can ı use in column because ı cant use, ı can use gradient color in container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just giving you an idea how to do that.

```
class ProfileupdateScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(home: MyPage());
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: ...),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Profile detail"),
              Image.asset("your_image"),
              Text("Bilgi ..."),
              TextField(), // Bugr...
              TextField(), // Zenc...
              TextField(), // email id
              DropdownButton(), // Erkek
              TextField(), // 10/12 ...
              DropdownButton(), // Ogre...
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(...),
    );
  }
}
```